# How can I narrow down which call is making a fully trusted call?

Tags: c#, asp.net, medium-trust

My host only allows medium trusted web applications.

I am getting this error:

```
Exception Details: System.Security.SecurityException: That assembly does not allow partially trusted callers.
```

I have the code, what should I change?
I read I can add a attribute in each file: [assembly:AllowPartiallyTrustedCallers]
but my solution has tons of files, is there a faster way to do this? (a single global change?)

**I wish I could narrow down which method or include namespace that is causing the issue.**
I don't even know if this assembly is signed or not.

Comment: What is the stack trace?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're deploying your web app as one or more assemblies, you should only have to add that attribute to AssemblyInfo.cs in each. . . This should really be more of a matter of making this change once per *project* not source file.

You should be able to do a Find in Files, set "Look at these types of files" to "AssemblyInfo.cs" and look for the text "assembly: AssemblyTitle"

You should only get one hit per project in your solution.

Answer (score 0):

Give this tool a shot.

http://www.charlesrcook.com/archive/2008/05/10/securityexception-that-assembly-does-not-allow-partially-trusted-callers.aspx